# Не могу сослаться на один html файл в другом html файле (файлы из разных папок)

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Начинаю учить spring и не могу понять, почему я не могу сослаться на один html-файл, находясь в другом html-файле (файлы из разных папок, но в одном проекте), точнее из html файла `hello` не виден html-файл `exit`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119). или хотя бы дублируйте картинки соответствующим текстом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно подняться на папку выше - "..", а затем перейти в нужную папку. Полный путь будет такой - "../second/exit.html"
Путь отсчитывается от вашего текущего местоположения файла.